# Zebra android SDK count TID and EPC

Tags: android, sdk, tags, rfid, zebra

I am working on Zebra Rfid reader android SDK. I downloaded sample code from https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/demo/123rfid-mobile.html and i want to modify this code.

I have RFID labels on my pallets. Each box has same EPC value in my pallet. Lets say I have 100 boxes in my pallet. Each RFID tag energized with the same EPC value.

Currently when I run, existing sample code counts different EPC numbers . So in my pallet, result is only 1.  I would like sample code to count TID values. So I will get 100 because each TID values are different in each labels. How can I count TID values with this sample code? What part I need to modify? Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried doing anything of this by yourself and are stuck on some part?

Answer (score 0):

After you have BT paired your RFID device to your Android device, you can see on the following image, where you read the tags screen, just select the TID as the memory bank, it should read the TID of the tags. I hope this may helps.

[image]